# SpringXD/Spring Integration: Using different versions of spring-integration-kafka for producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

I have the following configuration:

- Spring-integration-kafka 1.3.1.RELEASE
- I have a custom kafka-sink and a custom kafka-source

The configuration I want to have:

- I'd like to still using Spring-integration-kafka 1.3.1.RELEASE with my custom kafka-sink.
- I'm changing my kafka-source logic to use Spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE. I noticed the way to implement a consumer/producer is way different to prior versions of Spring-integration-kafka.

My question is: could I face some compatibily issues?

Comment: Which message bus are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rabbit.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Rabbit.

You should be ok then; it would probably work with the newer kafka jars in the source's `/lib` directory since each module is loaded in its own classloader so there should be no clashes with the `xd/lib` jars.

However, you might have to remove the old kafka jars from the `xd/lib` directory (which is why I asked about the message bus).